# Inverse of a sparse tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

I am trying to find the inverse of the following symmetric positive definite matrix :
$$
\left(\begin{array}{6*c}
 4&  1&0 & &\cdots&0\\ 
  1& 4&  1& &\huge0& \vdots \\ 
0&  \ddots& \ddots&  \ddots& & \\ 
\vdots &&  \ddots& \ddots&  \ddots&0\\ 
 & \huge 0 & &  1& 4&  1\\ 
 0& \cdots& &0&  1& 4
\end{array}\right)
$$

Of course the mathematical inverse of this matrix is full, however numerically I observed that the coefficients' magnitude of the inverse matrix are decreasing at an exponential rate around the diagonal.

Far from the border effect (*i.e.* for $i$ sufficiently greater than $1$ and lower than $n$) the diagonal pattern is the same up to $10^{-20}$: ($\forall j, i \neq i',  M^{-1}_{i'j} \approx M^{-1}_{ij} $). Moreover, I empirically check that this behavior does not depend on the dimension of the linear system $n$ (same pattern).

Do you have any clue on how to justify this observation? Or better, an analytical form to compute this inverse?

Cheers,

Leo.

Comment: See, e.g., [this review paper](http://scgroup.hpclab.ceid.upatras.gr/class/SCII/Various/Meurant_SML000707.pdf) and the references there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explicit formulas for inversion of tridiagonal matrices can be found in many places, e.g., https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01396436

A tridiagonal Toeplitz is just a special case. See for example in https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/144007569.pdf page 15.

Comment: Thanks that was exactly thte reference I was looking for